# JQuery - PHP Laravel DataTables - Not Displaying Data

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I've been trying to fix this all day but I haven't been able to fix it. Not sure what am I missing. Any help would be appreciated.

**RefillRequestController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\RefillRequest;
use App\Order;
use App\API;
use App\Package;

class RefillRequestController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
    return view('admin.refills.index');
}

public function indexData()
    {
    $refills = RefillRequest::join('orders', 'refill_requests.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->join('apis', 'orders.api_id', '=', 'apis.id')
    ->select('refill_requests.id as rid', 'refill_requests.status', 'apis.name', 'orders.api_order_id', 'orders.id', 'refill_requests.created_at')
    ->getQuery()->get();

    return datatables()
    ->of($refills)
    ->addColumn('details_url', function($refill) {
        return url('admin/refills/' . $refill->id . '/details');
    })
    ->addColumn('action', function($refill) {
        return view('admin.refills.index-buttons', compact('refill'));
    })
    ->editColumn('status', function($refill) {
        return '<span class=\'status-' . str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($refill->status)) . '\'>' . $refill->status . '</span>';
    })
    ->addColumn('api', function($refill) {
        return $refill->name;
    })
    ->addColumn('api_order_id', function($refill) {
        return $refill->api_order_id;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action', 'status'])->toJson();
}

public function indexFilter($status)
{
    return view('admin.refills.index', compact('status'));
}

public function indexFilterData($status)
{
    $status = ($status == 'inprogress' ? 'in progress' : $status);
    $refills = RefillRequest::join('orders', 'refill_requests.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->join('apis', 'orders.api_id', '=', 'apis.id')
    ->select('refill_requests.id as rid', 'refill_requests.status', 'apis.name', 'orders.api_order_id', 'orders.id', 'refill_requests.created_at')
    ->where(['refill_requests.status' => strtoupper($status)])
    ->getQuery()->get();
    return datatables()->of($refills)

    ->addColumn('details_url', function($refill) {
        return url('admin/refills/' . $refill->id . '/details');
    })
    ->addColumn('action', function($refill) {
        return view('admin.refills.index-buttons', compact('refill'));
    })
    ->editColumn('status', function($refill) {
        return '<span class=\'status-' . str_replace(' ', '', strtolower($refill->status)) . '\'>' . $refill->status . '</span>';
    })
    ->addColumn('api', function($refill) {
        return $refill->name;
    })
    ->addColumn('api_order_id', function($refill) {
        return $refill->api_order_id;
    })
    ->rawColumns(['action', 'status'])->toJson();
}

public function details(Order $order)
{
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'User', 
                'desc' => '<a href="/admin/users/' . $order->user->id . '/edit">' . $order->user->name . '</a>'
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Service', 
                'desc' => '<a href="/admin/services/' . $order->package->service->id . '/edit">' . $order->package->service->name . '</a>'
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Package', 
                'desc' => '<a href="/admin/packages/' . $order->package->id . '/edit">' . $order->package->name . '</a>'
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Link', 
                'desc' => '<a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="' . getOption('anonymizer') . $order->link . '" target="_blank">' . $order->link . '</a>'
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Amount', 
                'desc' => $order->price
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Quantity', 
                'desc' => $order->quantity
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Start Counter', 
                'desc' => $order->start_counter
              ];
    $data[] = [
                'name' => 'Order Date', 'desc' => $order->created_at
              ];
    return datatables()->of($data)->rawColumns(['desc'])->toJson();
}

public function changeStatus(RefillRequest $refill, $status)
{
    $str = strtolower($refill->status);

    switch ($str) {
    case 'pending':
        switch ($status) {
        case 'start':
            $refill->status = 'IN PROGRESS';
            break;
        case 'cancel':
            $refill->status = 'CANCELLED';
            $refill->order->status = 'COMPLETED';
            break;
        case 'complete':
            $refill->status = 'COMPLETED';
            $refill->order->status = 'COMPLETED';
            break;
        }

        break;
    case 'in progress':
        switch ($status) {
        case 'cancel':
            $refill->status = 'CANCELLED';
            $refill->order->status = 'COMPLETED';
            break;
        case 'complete':
            $refill->status = 'COMPLETED';
            $refill->order->status = 'COMPLETED';
            break;
        }

        break;
    }

    $refill->order->save();
    $refill->save();
    return back();
}
}

?>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<script id="details-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table class="table details-table mydatatable_details" id="refill-@{{id}}">

    </table>
</script> 
<script>
var template = Handlebars.compile($("#details-template").html());
var table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pageLength: 25,
        order: [[1, 'asc']],
        ajax: '{!! url($dataURL) !!}',
            columnDefs: [
                { targets: [6], className: "dt-right"},
            ],
        columns: [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "searchable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'api_order_id', name: 'api_order_id'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
        ]
});


// Add event listener for opening and closing details
$('#mydatatable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
    var tableId = 'refill-' + row.data().id;
    console.log(tableId);
    if (row.child.isShown()) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        row.child.hide();
        tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
        // Open this row
        row.child(template(row.data())).show();
        initTable(tableId, row.data());
        tr.addClass('shown');
        tr.next().find('td').addClass('no-padding bg-gray');
    }
});

function initTable(tableId, data) {
    console.log(data.details_url);
    $('#' + tableId).DataTable({
        // processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        ajax: data.details_url,
        columns: [
            { data: 'name', name: 'id' },
            { data: 'desc', name: 'unit' }
        ]
    })
}
</script>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/refills/list', 'RefillRequestController@index');
Route::get('/refills-ajax/data', 'RefillRequestController@indexData');
Route::get('/refills-filter/{status}', 'RefillRequestController@indexFilter');
Route::get('/refills-filter-ajax/{status}/data', 'RefillRequestController@indexFilterData');
Route::get('/refills/{order}/details', 'RefillRequestController@details');
Route::get('/refill/{refill}/{status}', 'RefillRequestController@changeStatus');
```

**APP/RefillRequest.php**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class RefillRequest extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }

    public function getStatusAttribute($status)
    {
        return title_case($status);
    }
}

?>
```

Now, I've tried to fix the code but unfortunately, the datatable is showing No data available in the table. MYSQL has data in the table named as "refill_requests" and the structure is http://prntscr.com/krxj1t

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? In your script you're referring to ```var table = $('#mydatatable').DataTable({``` and your <table> id = refill-(some_id). So that's not matching. Hope it helps

Comment: You are right but I have 2 tables created. The mydatatable will output the data and then inside there is another table based on the order ID.

Comment: If you mean master / details then there must be a better way to do this...